# visual studio 2022 - can't see tests on Test explorer

Tags: c#

I have few tests that exist ,I can even run them when I click on "play" on the test explorer.
but I can't see the tests line on the test explorer.
it worked before and stopped.
how to fix it?
here is an image that describes the test explorer:
[image]

Comment: look at log and search for discovery lines, also some test frameworks requires to have test classes and methods public

Comment: what log? how to reach it

Comment: In output window